# Django Celery task and transacrtion

Tags: django, transactions, celery

assuming that you have some Model that contains unique field and you have an async task that saves a new instance of the model to DB. something like this:

```
@shared_task
def create_model(model_identifier):
    with transaction.atomic():
        serializer=MyModelSerializer(data=model_data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.save()
        .
        .
        .
        some more actions
```

And you create 2 of those tasks one after the another, with the same identifier.
The first one will save the new instance first, so when the second one arrives to the 'save()' part - the object is already exists but it's not committed yet.
What should happen in that case?
If I get it right, it looks like when the second one arrives to the 'save()' (after the is_valid() passes), it awaits for the first one to finish the transaction (although they basically run in parallel) and only then an integrityError exception is raised.

Does it sound right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using @app.task instead of @shared_task

Document explaining @app.task
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application

Use apply_async for adding the task in the queue.

Comment: Thanks @Mihir Kavatkar, but what does that suppose to do? how does it answer the question? I tried it and it seems like nothing changed

Comment: I had a similar problem long time back and after messing around it, I was able to make it work with @app.task and in my case parallel execution was expected using multiple worker. Sorry, I was not helpful. I need to look into it again.